# PHP Open array of photo's from directory?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, glob

I'm making a Wordpress page template and I'm trying to add all the images from a directory to an array and then use a `foreach` to `echo` them all to the HTML. But when I try to load the page I get this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`, so this means it is not an array, but it worked before. I also tried it with the `scandir` function but that would give me the error `[function.scandir]: failed to open dir: not implemented in`. The PHP code is used is included below.

```
$folder = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/dir/';
$images = glob($folder . "*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($images as $image)
{
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" />';
}
```

The path to the folder is correct because with the code below I get one picture.

```
echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/dir/image.jpg" />';
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `vardump( $images ); `

Comment: Tried to `var_dump()` your `$images` before `foreach()`? Check if it's `null` or `false`, because that will make difference, as manual says `Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the `var_dump()` function and it returns `bool(false)`. There are images in the directory I want to open. Is there a way to make an array of `$images`?

Answer (score 1):

I think template_directory returns a URL in wordpress now, if you use [get_template_directory()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) that will return the absolute path. (it doesn't return a trailing slash so you need to remember to add that)

That could be the issue you are having, worth a shot.

If you use a child theme use [get_stylesheet_directory()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)

Comment: This fixed the `foreach()` error! Now I only have to fix the path to the images and it should work.

Comment: Well the images use URLs, so when creating your image tag in the loop, you should use bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") to get your URL to the theme folder, then add the rest of the path to the end and the filename from $image and voila

Answer (score 0):

php's [`glob()` function](http://php.net/glob) will return `false` on error (or when no matched files are found, depending on your os).

I suspect in your specific case the return value is indeed `false` (as `foreach` can work with empty array's, it'll basically just skip the block). Try to find out: `var_dump($images);`.

You should add a check to make sure the return value is indeed something you can work with:

```
if(is_array($images)) {
    foreach($images as $image) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: I've added the `if()` statement and it just skips the block as you said so `$images` is not an array. Is there a workaround to make an array of `$images`?

Comment: a workaround? well, if it's not an array, you don't get the desired output ;) so you'll have to fix the code you use to grab the images... Try debugging the script, first of all by finding out _why_ it isn't an array, meaning, why it can't find the files you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

The problem is path. You try  `'/img/directory/';` and this isn't working. And later you say that `'/img/dir/image.jpg'` is working. Do you see **directory** and **dir**?

You have mispelled path, that's all.

Comment: Yeah sorry, this was just done for illustrative purposes, those different paths are not the problem. Well spotted though!

Comment: @MaxRuigewaard Well, if you change your code before posting here, you may also change the nature of problem. I'd post raw code anyway. You can also echo path to folder before loop and check if its really correct. Maybe there is `//` instead of `/` or other typo.